# When using your own FMS/AMS for both RTMP and P2P RTMFP, is there any way to allow BitmapData.draw() to work without a security sandbox exception?

Tags: flash, security, apache-flex, exception, air

I put something in one of our video chat programs to capture screenshots from that program and save them to disk, and it works, except when video streams are being received.  I tracked the problem down to a call to `BitmapData.draw()` in the class `ImageSnapshot`, which was throwing error #2123 (a security sandbox exception).

Looking around, there appears to be a security setting in the FMS/AMS configuration to get past this security issue with RTMP streams, but a lot of people are complaining about there not being anything for P2P RTMFP streams.  Glancing at one proposed workaround, people were talking about sending images across the wire, but I can't do that; it's too dangerously hacked together, and when multiple remote streams are loaded, it'll always produce invalid, out-of-sync screenshots.  I need a way to take screenshots for real.

Some of these posts are five years old, and I know there were bug reports that are that old.  Is there any way, in Flex, to get past this issue for both RTMP and P2P RTMFP streams?  We're just needing it for Adobe AIR, which is usually a little more relaxed on security restrictions.  We're also using our own server, even for P2P RTMFP.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check this question and answer. There are FMS configuration and code changes. [Using your own AMS, how can you use BitmapData.draw() on an RTMP stream with no security exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990674/using-your-own-ams-how-can-you-use-bitmapdata-draw-on-an-rtmp-stream-with-no/23058631#23058631)