# Using your own AMS, how can you use BitmapData.draw() on an RTMP stream with no security exception?

Tags: actionscript-3, security, air, rtmp, flash-media-server

I've posted a similar question about the more general case, but this question deals specifically with RTMP.

We have an Adobe AIR app written in AS3 that can view live video streams from other parties.  That being said, when trying to call `BitmapData.draw()` on one of those remote video streams (technically we're calling `ImageSnapshot.captureImage()`), we're getting a 2123 error - a security sandbox exception.  I've seen a lot of people refer to a real simple configuration in the AMS that will allow this to work for RTMP streams, but they keep posting broken links, links to posts that only vaguely mention this configuration, etc.  The one thing I did find is something that I'm having trouble applying:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashMediaServer/3.5_SS_ASD/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a11afc95e-7ec3.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a11afc95e-7fcb

To make the above work, I've tried setting `audioSampleAccess` and `videoSampleAccess` both to `"/"`, but to no avail.  On the AMS, in Application.xml, I've set these configurations:

```
<FolderAccess>true</FolderAccess>
<AudioSampleAccess enabled="true">*</AudioSampleAccess>
<VideoSampleAccess enabled="true">*</VideoSampleAccess>
```

I've also seen references to setting up a wide-open cross-domain policy file, but I've seen people emphasize that it's not necessary, and I don't see any clear mention of where on the server that policy file needs to be.  I have, however, started setting `NetStream.checkPolicyFile` to `true`, and I have placed a cross-domain policy file in the root directory of the website itself (as opposed to the AMS).

Please don't just give me another link, unless it's to a quick, clear explanation.  How do you configure the AMS to allow people to capture screenshots from RTMP video streams?  For the above article, I've tried setting videoStreamAccess and audioStreamAccess both to "/", and even it didn't work.  We also need to be able to do this for P2P RTMFP streams, but that's really a different question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have following FMS code to fix that error in application.onConnect method:

```
client.videoSampleAccess = "/";
client.audioSampleAccess = "/";
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have tried that though, and it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: These 2 options (xml config and client code properties) are only 2 I used in both wowza and fms. Both in standalone mode (no AWS). I suggest: 1) recheck that you connect to correct app instance on server. 2) ensure that no other UI elements captured by ImageSnapshot.captureImage(). Maybe you have other elements except video that can cause security error. Externally loaded image for example. Try to call ImageSnapshot.captureImage() without video on stage to verify that.